# Import OSM data to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, geojson, openstreetmap

since last few days I am trying to import data from OpenStreetMap to MongoDB. After importing geojson to database cant create any index, beacuse of various errors described below.

Hello, since last few days I am trying to import data from OpenStreetMap to MongoDB. After importing geojson to database cant create any index, beacuse of various errors described below.
Steps to download and load files to databse, maybe you can find what I am doing wrong.

1. Download data with overpass api and save as JSON file using python

```
import requests
import json

overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
overpass_query = """
[out:json][timeout:600];
area["ISO3166-1"="PL"][admin_level=2];
(way["natural"="water"]["water"="lake"](area);
 relation["natural"="water"]["water"="lake"](area);
);
out geom;
"""
response = requests.get(overpass_url,
                        params={'data': overpass_query})
data = response.json()
```

2. Format data with `osmtojson` and `jq`:

```
node --max_old_space_size=10000 `which osmtogeojson` input.json | ./jq-linux64 --compact-output ".features" > ../data_geojson/output.geojson
```

I was following instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029114/how-to-import-geojson-file-to-mongodb).

3. Insert data with mongoimport:

```
mongoimport -d <db> -c <col> --file output.geojson --jsonArray -j 4 --batchSize=1000
```

Inserting is successful but when trying to create `2dsphere` index I am getting errors about `Unclosed Loop` for polygons or duplicates in nodes.

Do you know any package or script to help clear my data before inserting to db? Or maybe I am missing something in my steps?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/docs). Maybe it gives better error messages and perhaps some "repair" methods. Or try the online GeoJSON validator: https://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am dealing with quite big files ~2GB each. Online tools may fail, but I will try them, thanks :)

Comment: Another alternative could be https://terraformer-js.github.io/